# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a weakest topology such that some functions are continuous.

Tags: general-topology, measurable-functions, borel-sets

I am wondering about statements like : Let $X$ be a vector space, let $\tau$ be the weakest topology such that some set of functional $F$ are continuous. Let also $\Sigma$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$. I'm wondering if $\Sigma$ is the weakest $\sigma$-algebra such that all $f\in F$ are measurable.

It is clear that any $f\in F$ is measurable, since any continuous function is measurable. This shows that the weakest $\sigma$-algebra such that $f\in F$ are measurable is contained in $\Sigma$. I'm not sure how to prove the other direction (or if it is true at all).

Comment: Interesting subquestion: it’s known that for a reals to reals function that is merely additive, continuity and measurabIlity are equivalent. Does this extend to functionals on vector spaces (for vector space topologies) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Consider the collection of all functions of the form $\chi_{\{x\}}, x \in \mathbb R$. The weak topology generated by this is the discrete topology since each singleton set is open. So $\Sigma$ is  the power set of $\mathbb R$. But the smallest $\sigma -$ algebra making each $\chi_{\{x\}}$ measurable is the $\sigma-$ algebra of countable and co-countable sets.

Notation: $\chi_A (y)=1$ if $ y \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Nice but note that these are not **functionals**. It's more subtle there.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma A functional on a vector space is a scalar valued function. You are probably confusing it with 'linear functional'.

Comment: the OP meant linear functional I think. On a vector space all “functionals” are assumed to be linear. I don’t consider a norm function to be a functional merely a special type of real function.